# Dependent variable is count data, which method to use?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, poisson-regression

Which method should I use to analyse the relationship between count variable (absent days) and other 4 variables?
Should I standardise Size variable?
Please recommend some further literature/ tutorials to go deeper into this topic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the goal of your modelling? There are many threads here about poisson regression, look into those. And, looking at your variable "Absent days", it has very many zeroes, look into zero-inflated count models.

Comment: The goal is to see which variable has the highest influence on variable Absent_days (number of days a worker is absent from his job). 
I speculated that Poisson regression should be the most suitable, but data is very dispersed. So, probable the solution is Zero-inflated Negative Binominal model?
I am totally new in this field, but eager to study it.

Comment: It isn't really possible to determine "which variable has the highest influence", because the variables are incommensurate. Other than that issue, what is wrong w/ using regular count regression models? If there are special issues in your data (eg, overdispersion, zero-inflation, etc), you need to put that info in the body of the question. We aren't going to be able to tell from the image you clipped.

Comment: I mean, I would like to run regression to explain the counts of variable Absent_days. I am first time dealing with that kind of models, so I was not really sure, what is important. I am familiar with count regression models: Poisson, Neg Binomial regression, Zero-Inflated and Hurlde models. But I do not know, which one is the most suitable. 

Mean (absent days) = 5.242268
var(absent days) = 337.3141

Comment: Your tags were well chosen and so you can find threads on the key topics you've rightly identified. But I don't think you're likely to get a fuller answer than the comments so far. As @gung emphasizes, we don't have the ability to foresee what will work best with your data. Do try some analyses and then come back with specific questions as they arise.

Comment: I believe I am much closer to the solution of my problem. Since we deal with overdisperzion, negative binomial regression has to be applied. 
But one question remains! Should predictors be standardized? In my case I get significant results only if I standardise predictor Size?

Comment: What is variable *Size*? Is it some measure of firm size (number of employees, or some similar?) If so, that variable should be an offset!